# appharbor force HTTPS for static files

Tags: appharbor

I have a requirement to ensure all traffic on my website is redirected to HTTPS if it is requested over HTTP. When we deploy the site to appharbor, we use the custom RequireHttpsAttribute which works well for our MVC controllers.

However we also want to force any request for static files (images, stylesheets, javascript) via HTTP to be sent to HTTPS. Trying it using the web.config rewrite rules ends up in a redirect loop due to the load balancer sending https request to the web server as http.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

After receiving a reply from appharbor support, one of their suggestions was to implement code similar to the custom RequireHttpsAttribute for static files as well.
So I created a class called HttpRequestModule, and set it up to run for all requests (runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests set to true) I was able to force any direct requests to HTTP urls to redirect to HTTPS.

```
class HttpRequestModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Init(HttpApplication app)
    {
        app.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(CheckHttpRequest);
    }

    private void CheckHttpRequest(object sender, EventArgs a)
    {
        if (app.Context.Request.IsSecureConnection) return;

        if (app.Contact.Request.IsLocal) return;

        if (string.Equals(app.Context.Request.Headers["X-Forwarded-Proto"],
            "https",
            StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            return;
        }

        var secureUrl = "https://" + app.Context.Request["HTTP_HOST"] + HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl;
        app.Context.Response.Redirect(secureUrl);
    }
}
```